# Why do these tests fail when run simultaneously, yet each passes individually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am experiencing strange very test behavior, with logged in state being handled inconsistently.

The spec logs a user in, visits a (nested or un-nested) index page, and checks that the correct content is displayed. Records are fetched asynchronously, though I don't think this should have an impact.

When each spec is run individually, they each pass. When all specs are run together, they fail because the expected content is missing. Using `save_and_open_page` reveals this is because the login page is being rendered, rather than the expected index page.

Why does rspec think the user is not signed in when all specs are run together, yet each spec passes individually?

The tests look something like this

```
let(:user) {create :user}
let(:team) {create :team}
let(:country) {create :country}

before :each do 
  login_as( user, scope: :user )
end

describe 'unnested' do
  it 'should have the expected content', :js do 
    visit users_path
    is_expected.to have_content "some content on the page"
  end
end

describe 'nested by team' do
  it 'should have the expected content', :js do 
    visit team_users_path(team)
    is_expected.to have_content "some content on the page"
  end
end

describe 'nested by nationality' do
  it 'should have the expected content', :js do 
    visit country_users_path(country)
    is_expected.to have_content "some content on the page"
  end
end
```

The specs all require javascript (I don't know whether that is important here).

Authentication is handled by Devise, and my `rails_helper.rb` includes

```
config.append_after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
  Warden.test_reset!
end
```

Why does rspec think the user is not signed in when all specs are run together, yet each spec passes individually?

Answer (score 0):

It took a long time to get to the bottom of this. Posting this hear in case it is of help to anyone else encountering the same issue.

After much searching I eventually found [this small mention](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara#capybara-and-poltergeist) that `login_as may not work with Poltergeist when js is enabled on your test scenarios.`

I tried the suggested fix to deal with shared DB connections. Unfortunately this resulted in the following errors:

```
PG::DuplicatePstatement at /session/users/signin
ERROR:  prepared statement "a1" already exists
```

I tried using the [Transactional Capybara](https://github.com/iangreenleaf/transactional_capybara) gem, but this did not seem to work well with Poltergeist.

Eventually I abandonned `login_as` completely, and instead wrote a short method that visits the login page, fills in email and password, and logs in that way.

This solution appears to be working. It adds a little overhead, so I'm only using it for tests with JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Capybara gem then there is no need to use :js with test cases

What I did if this helps-

```
scenario "visit with user signed in" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  login_as(user, :scope => :user)
  visit "/"
  expect(current_path).to eq('/')
  expect(page).to have_title "Some Random Title"
end
```

The other way you can login user using feature specs like-

```
feature 'User signs in' do
  before :each do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  scenario "Signing in with correct credentials" do
    visit "/"
    fill_in "Email", with: @user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: @user.password
    click_button "Log In"
    expect(current_path).to eq("/login/useremail/verification")
    expect(page).to have_content "Signed in successfully"
  end  
end
```

If your pages are ajax then refer to this  https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara